# slick 3.0.0 with HikariCP driver not loaded - IllegalAccessException: AbstractHikariConfig can not access a member with modifiers "private"

Tags: scala, reflection, slick, hikaricp, slick-3.0

I am trying to use [tminglei/slick-pg v9.0.0](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) with slick 3.0.0 and am getting an `IllegalAccessException`:

```
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:166) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: driverClassName specified class 'com.github.tminglei.MyPostgresDriver$' could not be loaded
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig.setDriverClassName(AbstractHikariConfig.java:370) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.8.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$$anonfun$forConfig$18.apply(JdbcDataSource.scala:145) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$$anonfun$forConfig$18.apply(JdbcDataSource.scala:145) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:145) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:135) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:35) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$class.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:223) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$$anon$3.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:33) ~[slick_2.11-3.0.0.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig can not access a member of class com.github.tminglei.MyPostgresDriver$ with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:373) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig.setDriverClassName(AbstractHikariConfig.java:366) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.8.jar:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

HikariCP is the default connection pool in slick 3.0.0

I have defined the driver class much like in the [example](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/e346bd72b65ea9999482328fdf64915ab49cd276/examples/codegen-customization/codegen/src/main/scala/demo/MyPostgresDriver.scala):

```
trait MyPostgresDriver extends ExPostgresDriver with PgArraySupport
  with PgEnumSupport
  with PgRangeSupport
  with PgHStoreSupport
  with PgSearchSupport{

  override val api = new MyAPI {}

  //////
  trait MyAPI extends API
  with ArrayImplicits
  with RangeImplicits
  with HStoreImplicits
  with SearchImplicits
  with SearchAssistants

}

object MyPostgresDriver extends MyPostgresDriver
```

My database config is pretty straightforward [excerpt of typesafe config follows]:

```
slick.dbs.default {

  driver="com.github.tminglei.MyPostgresDriver$"

  db {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

    url="jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname"
    user=user
    password="pass"
  }
}
```

It does not seem as if it should not work, *and yet...*

Should I change my driver class somehow? Is it something else?

Note: as can be seen in the stacktrace I am using

1. Java 1.7.0_79
2. Scala 2.11.7
3. akka 2.3.11 (I share the config instance for slick and akka)
4. slick 3.0.0
5. HikariCP-java6 2.3.8
6. tminglei's slick-pg_core 0.9.0

---

***Lastly,*** when debugging thru the jdk code at Class.class (decompiled line 143)

```
 Constructor tmpConstructor1 = this.cachedConstructor;
```

I get the following (toString'ed) value (as shown by intellij):

```
private com.github.tminglei.MyPostgresDriver$()
```

Could this be indicative of the problem? If so how should I fix it?

---

***EDIT***

I have replaced the custom driver configuration with the stock PostgresDriver like so:

```
slick.dbs.default {

  driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"

  db {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

    url="jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname"
    user=user
    password="pass"
  }
}
```

The error is the same:

```
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: driverClassName specified class 'slick.driver.PostgresDriver$' could not be loaded
    ... 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.zaxxer.hikari.AbstractHikariConfig can not access a member of class slick.driver.PostgresDriver$ with modifiers "private"
```

Comment: It seems like this could be caused by a private constructor ... ?

Comment: it would seem so, but I can't figure out where... as you can imagine, I am pretty new to Scala...

Comment: @brettw added edit. It would seem as if the stock driver doesn't work as well

Comment: While this is not a Play Framework question per se, you are likely to find a lot of help over there as there are helpful Scala guys and Slick 3.0 guys there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

I think you are using `Database.forConfig("slick.dbs.default")` but your config file is in [DatabaseConfig](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html?highlight=pool#databaseconfig) format.

Instead, try using:

```
val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[PostgresDriver] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("slick.dbs.default")
val db = dbConfig.db
```

Comment: Thanks! Did the job perfectly! I would have been at my wits end if not for you response :)